# Am I over-specifying the positioning of my 'matplotlib' annotations?

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, label

I want to be able to specify a relative position for callout labels on data points in my `matplotlib` plots using basic compass orientations ('NW', 'E', etc.)

[image]

and have written some code that works; but I'm confused about the settings for annotation and arrow positioning and am wondering of I've over-specified the positions and relationships among arrows, alignment, and locations.

Are all these settings really necessary to achieve the result I'm looking for, or is there perhaps a more compact way to accomplish my goal:

```
fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()
for loc in ['N', 'S', 'E', 'W', 'NW', 'SW', 'NE', 'SE']:
    pts = (1 if len(loc) == 1 else 1/math.sqrt(2))*50
    ax.annotate(loc, (0.5, 0.5),
                ha='right' if 'W' in loc else ('left' if 'E' in loc else 'center'),
                va='bottom' if 'N' == loc else ('top' if 'S' == loc else 'center'),
                xytext=((-1 if 'W' in loc else (1 if 'E' in loc else 0))*pts,
                        (-1 if 'S' in loc else (1 if 'N' in loc else 0))*pts),
                textcoords='offset points',
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-', connectionstyle='arc3',
                                relpos=(1 if 'W' in loc else (0 if 'E' in loc else 0.5),
                                        0 if 'N' == loc else (1 if 'S' == loc else 0.5))))
```